# How to Make Menu in Android

Tags: android, menu

i want to menu like website's one menu->more than one sub menu.but,i have no idea creating like this and i want to like one menu under more than one sub menu's can any one help me with code or tutorial link with greatly appreciated!

i want ouput like below screen shot:

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

**quickActionDialog** will be helpful in your specific requirement.

Here is link for **QuickActionDialog** library and implementation.

[NewQuickAction3D](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D)

[NewQuickAction](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction)